# Are there other audiobooks with the quality and immersion of Phil Dragash's LOTR?

Tags: audiobooks

Either a collection, specific book, or known narrator would be fine.

Note: If you haven't heard Phil Dragash, he incorporates the movie soundtrack, background noise and other voices into his audiobook. Free. It's fantastic.

Comment: This site is not for book (or audiobook) recommendations. It's for asking questions related to the production and use of ebooks.